# prevent create new div when reach min height or pasting text

Tags: php, html, asp.net, css

I have the following html:

```
<div id='parent' align='right' dir='rtl'   style=padding:0px;margin:0px;font-weight: bold;width:300px;height:auto;min-height:300px; "'<div  align='right' dir='rtl'  ><br /></div></div>
```

I have set the above code inside ( html editor) but in some cases when I write more text  inside parent div and it reached the min-height or when pasting some text inside it, or pressing  more `<br />` then new  parent div created automatically with the same css. My target is to prevent create new parent div and just make the content inside parent div, without create new div.

Comment: you forgot the html part.

Comment: No the problem only in this part , I want to prevent to generate new div when parent div reached its height , I want to increase its height without create new duv

Comment: I'm not understand. I need to see some code.
I have no idea what you talking about. what div?
By default div's not creates automatically.

Comment: @Dvir he included the HTML, just never code formatted it. I edited it so you can see it now... don't know if it will help as it doesn't even look valid. I hope its just typo in the post and not his real code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Wouldn't you just be able to increase the height of your div?

Comment: I have text editor and I put div inside it with height:auto and min-height: 300px but the problem , when I press enter , new  div created automatically and the page height go to be too long

Comment: Isn't this a comment?